# Make my developed app browser to be recognized for "open by default" android function

Tags: android, browser, default, system-setting

I'm not a pro Android programmer, but I developed my custom browser app. Easy application which contain a `WebView` and a `SearchView`. Now I want that when I tap on a link my browser app is opened by default, but I can't set it by default because it doesn't appear into "select browser" popup(I can see only the stock browser and Chrome). The question is, there is the possibility to set my app as default browser app ? And if yes, how ?

PS: Sorry if this question was already been done but I searched a lot on the internet but could not find anything that helped me.

Comment: @Rotwang Instead I think that it is. See the best answer that I have chosen, it's code (XML) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set your app is display on "Select browser" popup, add this code in activity tag in manifest file:

```
 <intent-filter >
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:scheme="http" />
       <data android:scheme="https" />

  </intent-filter>
```

Now you app appears in Select browser popup, make it default by clicking Always button.